# New Language Files

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I am user of Joomla 2.5 cms and I try to built a double-language site.

Yesterday I installed this one module to my site

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/authentication-management/6660

but this don't support 2 languages, only one.

The help I need is some information on how I can add new files for this module with new labels of course at my excisting language packages.

Comment: Do you mean doesn't use JText at all (so translations will not work) or that it doesn't have a language package for your language?

Comment: No language package, no JText at all

Comment: They don't even have an English language pack?

Comment: There is an english package from the first day of Joomla 2.5 installation, but you know it doesn't support the components which you upload and installed later.

Comment: Does the component you installed have language files or not? I'm not asking you about the core CMS I am asking you about the specific extension you installed, does it have a language folder?

Comment: @Elin, just check the plugin and module. Neither have any language folders/files, nor is it using `JText` anywhere. They've not made this dynamic at all. Everything is "hard coded" so making any changes is going to take time any effort should you ever want to install an update. Very surprised they have not got this project on the likes of Github

Comment: Well the probably don't because it is a mess if they haven't followed basic best practices ... so what you'd have to do is rewrite the code using JText and make en-GB language files for the current strings.  Then make a language file for your language.  What a pain.

Comment: Can i make a double lang package with these instructions
http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_language_packs_for_extensions_in_Joomla_2.5?

Comment: Something else, is there anybody who knows about a multilanguage module for Joomla 2.5 which provides control registration?I want something with passphrase/password, not Captcha.
thanx a lot to everybody!!!

Answer (score 1):

if it doesn't support 2 languages, you have some problems

anyway you can ask your developer to help you.
or you can check the source and change the needed words to your desire language, then you can change the module name and install it separately

it is important to see if you have the right to change that extension.

and you can write your own of course :)